# 'smoothstep' : no matching overloaded function found

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, smoothstep

I am going through the [Book of Shaders tutorial](https://thebookofshaders.com/07/) on GLSL and I attempt to use the `smoothstep` function but I get this error. You can see it happen when I changed the `step` to the `smoothstep` function below.

```
// Author @patriciogv - 2015
// http://patriciogonzalezvivo.com

#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform vec2 u_mouse;
uniform float u_time;

void main(){
    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution.xy;
    vec3 color = vec3(0.0);

    // bottom-left
    vec2 bl = smoothstep(vec2(0.1),st); 
    float pct = bl.x * bl.y;

    // top-right 
    // vec2 tr = step(vec2(0.1),1.0-st);
    // pct *= tr.x * tr.y;

    color = vec3(pct);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(color,1.0);
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Put your code in the question, not a picture of it.

Comment: Sure! Thanks for being super unhelpful!

Comment: How did you fix this @jumbopap ? I'm getting this when i'm trying to use `step` in a Codepen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`step` and `smootstep` are 2 functions with a different signature and behavior.
While `step` generates a hard transition from 0 to 1 at an edge, `smoothstep` smoothly interpolates between 2 values.

As specified in the Khronos reference, [`smoothstep`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/smoothstep.xhtml) has 3 parameters:

```
genType smoothstep( genType edge0, genType edge1, genType x );
```

- `edge0` Specifies the value of the lower edge of the Hermite function.
- `edge1` Specifies the value of the upper edge of the Hermite function.
- `x` Specifies the source value for interpolation.

> smoothstep performs smooth Hermite interpolation between 0 and 1 when `edge0 < x < edge1`. This is useful in cases where a threshold function with a smooth transition is desired.

In comparison, [`step`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/step.xhtml) has 2 parameters:

```
genType step( genType edge, genType x);
```

- `edge` Specifies the location of the edge of the step function.
- `x` Specify the value to be used to generate the step function.

> `step` generates a step function by comparing x to edge.
>   For element `i` of the return value, 0.0 is returned `if x[i] < edge[i]`, and 1.0 is returned otherwise.